# H.ui.Control with React

Tags: here-api

I'm looking to add a react element with H.ui.Control. Is this possible? and how might it be done?

```
// sudo code of what I did
componentDidMount() {
  ...
  let button = new H.ui.Control(this.myButtonControl);
  button.setPosition('top-left');
  this._ui.addControl('button-control', button);
  ...
}

myButtonControl() {
  return <button className="H_btn">Hello World</button>
}
```

A new `<div class="H_ctl"></div>`, appears where the control was suppose to be, but not the button.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not exactly what I wanted to do, I did find a solution. I created a generic class that extends `H.ui.Control`, in this case ButtonGroupControl.

```
class ButtonGroupControl extends H.ui.Control {
  constructor(buttons: []) {
    super();
    this._buttons = buttons;
    this.addClass('H_grp');
  }

  renderInternal(el, doc) {
    this._buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
      let btn = doc.createElement('button');
      btn.className = 'H_btn';
      btn.innerText = this._buttons[i].label;
      btn.onclick = this._buttons[i].callback;
      el.appendChild(btn);
    })
    super.renderInternal(el, doc);
  }
}

export default ButtonGroupControl;
```

Then, inside my map component, I created passed array of items into the control, like so:

```
const mapToolsControl: ButtonGroupControl = new ButtonGroupControl([
    {
        label: 'Add Field',
        callback: () => {
          console.log('callback: adding field');
        }
    },
    {
        label: 'Remove Field',
        callback: () => {
          console.log('callback: remove field');
        }
    }
]);
```

Lastly, I added the control to the map like:

```
this._map.addControl('map-tools-control', mapToolsControl);
```

This results in the following (it's a link because I don't have enough points to embed yet):
[Screenshot of Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjcu2.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i have done (adding two buttons to the map)

```
var U_I = new H.ui.UI(map);

var container = new H.ui.Control();
container.addClass('here-ctrl here-ctrl-group');

var button = new H.ui.base.Element('button', 'here-ctrl-icon map_control');
container.addChild(button);
button.addEventListener('click', function() { alert(1); });

var button = new H.ui.base.Element('button', 'here-ctrl-icon map_center');
container.addChild(button);
button.addEventListener('click', function() { alert(2); });

container.setAlignment('top-right');

U_I.addControl('myControls', container );
U_I.addControl('ScaleBar', new H.ui.ScaleBar() );
```

the rendering is made by css (here is an extract)

```
button.here-ctrl-icon {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.map_control { background: url("images/map_control.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; }
.map_center  { background: url("images/map_center.png")  no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent; }
```

- `H.ui.base.Button();`  is not working ... it creates a div
- It is not possible to add attributes to `button` such as `alt` or `title` thru the api.
- I still have to deal with the addEventListener ... (not working !)

the result :

[my new nice controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CwMj.png)